# Pattern/regex formatting for Python fnmatch

Tags: python, regex

All of my filenames contain the following pattern:

```
datasetname_%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.out
```

The timestamp is added using `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")`

What I want to do is check to see if the filename already contains the timestamp, and if it does, strip it off.  For that I can use `split`.  And I can use `fnmatch` to test if the filename contains the pattern.

The part I'm having trouble with is figuring out the regex pattern to give `fnmatch` from the format I'm using.

Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The whole pattern or just `%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S`?

Comment: I just want to strip off the timestamp, and actually the extension can be stripped off too. So say for example I have a file called `mydataset_2013-09-10_23.25.01`, I want to first check to see if the file contains a timestamp matching the aforementioned format, and if it does, strip off everything after the underscore, leaving me with `mydataset`.  For that, I can use split.  But to do the check, I need to provide fnmatch with a pattern to look for that matches the timestamp pattern.

Comment: Possibly just do `[\d-_\.]+` or the long way `_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}`

Comment: howsabout `_([0-9-_.]+)\.`

Comment: fnmatch does not take a regex

Comment: @WombatPM you can use `fnmatch.translate` for regex

Comment: @hwnd translate only converts a unix shell-style pattern into a regex, it does not allow you to use a regex in fnmatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up seeming to work for me:

```
regexp = re.compile('_([0-9-_.]+\...)')
if regexp.search(fileName) is not None:
    #Do something with the filename
```

I used the pattern based on drewk's comment above (thank you).  So far the pattern seems to work, but it might need some tweaking.  In any case, it got me a lot further than where I was.

Also thanks to WombatPM.  Your answer actually helped with a separate problem I was having.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be making this more complicated than it needs to be.

from the python documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

> This module provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards, which are
>   not the same as regular expressions (which are documented in the re
>   module).

If your datasetname is **derf** the example becomes:

```
    import fnmatch
    import os

    dsn = 'derf_'

    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, dsn+'*.out'):
            print file
```

Comment: Good point. It looks like re might be the way to go. Thank you.